# pulse shaping filter and passband

Tags: digital-communications

Most of the time, the baseband transmission chain is: modulation->oversampling->shaping filter (SRRC)->bandpass conversion on a carrier frequency $f_0$.

But can we change the previous order like that?
modulation (baseband)->bandpass conversion on a carrier frequency $f_0$.->oversampling->shaping filter (SRRC)

Comment: did I answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes they can be interchanged, and in this case a bandpass shaping filter would be used. However having the pulse-shaping filter as a low pass filter prior to the up-conversion may be preferred given the significantly narrower occupied bandwidth of the resulting waveform. This increases the possible frequencies that can be used as the digital IF frequency without aliasing distortion.